# How can i use webfonts for emails in odoo8?

Tags: email, templates, fonts, odoo

I want use a webfont in a odoo email template.

My code was:

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molle:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<p style="font-family: 'Molle', cursive; font-size: 24px;">test text in schreibschrift</p>

I believe odoo filter the email code before sending and removes some html tags.

The link tag is not in the  received email, as shown in Thunderbird.

How can i bypass this?

Comment: Recommendation: don't. Almost no email client supports @font-face, so instead of making the content look reasonable enough using only the "web safe" set, you're now going to be designing your mails with fonts that are almost guaranteed not to load for a large portion of your clients, and because you're no longer designing using the fonts they *will* see, things will look far worse than if you'd stuck with the basic fonts.

Comment: see https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email, updated October 15th, 2015

Comment: As another evidence, Odoo itself from saas-6 (version between 8.0 and 9.0) has a system of Pictogram using FontAwesome, but when sending the mail these pictogram [are transformed to image](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/38d7e563aa7181947e66432558d358f199fc8693/addons/web_editor/controllers/main.py#L69-L128) instead of including the FontAwesome font.